# Shiny SelectInputs to Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I'm trying to learn R and am running into issues using the Shiny dashboard GUI. I'm trying to turn these SelectInputs

```
tabItem(tabName = "data",
          fluidRow(
            selectInput("Telecommuting", "Telecommute (Yes=1, No=0)", c("1","0")),
            selectInput("logo", "Has Logo(Yes=1, No=0)", c("1","0")),
            selectInput("questions", "Has Questions(Yes=1, No=0)", c("1","0")),
```

into dataframe inputs that I call at the top of my dashboard script

```
dfTemp<- read.csv('words.csv', header=T)
```

The CSV is just a one row csv with all values initialized to 0. I want to take the SelectInputs by the user and place them into the dataframe according to the input.

```
  storeCommute<- renderText(input$Telecommuting)
dfTemp$telecommuting<- storeCommute
```

However when I try to set the dfTemp$telecommuting to the storeCommute input, I get an error:

```
Error in xj[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I have searched for hours and there is no info on how to get this done. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Try to make a small reproducible example of your issue so others can help. That means a small version of your app with all the libraries as well as the server and the ui with your issue present.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is doable yet quite complicated due to the nature of `selectInput`. Below is an example which I think would very close to what you write and the example include various usage of different input ui, reactive values, and event handling in Shiny.

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# ui part
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Trial Input added rows to a dataframe"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        # a text input for input random word
        textInput(inputId = "word",
                  label = 'Word', width = "300px")
      ),
      fluidRow(
        # a checkbox for Yes/No values - telecommute
        checkboxInput(inputId = "telecommute",
                      label = 'Telecommuting',
                      value = FALSE)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        # a checkbox for Yes/No values - logo
        checkboxInput(inputId = "logo",
                      label = 'Has Logo',
                      value = FALSE)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        # a checkbox for Yes/No values - questions
        checkboxInput(inputId = "questions",
                      label = 'Has Questions',
                      value = FALSE)
      ),
      fluidRow(
        # Action button that added rows to the reactive value df on click
        actionButton(inputId = "add_rows", label = "Add rows")
      )
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        #  data.frame output - will change follow each "add_rows" click
        tableOutput(outputId = "data_table")
      ),
      fluidRow(
        # Action button that save the current data to words.csv
        actionButton(inputId = "save_csv", label = "Save to csv")
      )
    )
  )
)

# server part
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # reactive values that store df_temp for later processing & visualization
  values <- reactiveValues(
    df_temp = 
      {
        # for the first time running if no words.csv available 
        # an empty tibble is created.
        data <- tibble(word = character(0),
                       telecommute = logical(0),
                       logo = logical(0),
                       questions = logical(0))
        if (file.exists("./words.csv")) {
          # if words.csv exist load the data from csv file
          data <- read.csv("./words.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        }
        data
      }
  )
  
  # server code handling logic added row to values$df_temp
  observeEvent(input$add_rows, {
    values$df_temp <- bind_rows(values$df_temp, 
                                tibble(word = input$word,
                                       telecommute = input$telecommute,
                                       logo = input$logo,
                                       questions = input$questions))
  })
  
  # render the values$df_temp to a table output to UI
  output$data_table <- renderTable(values$df_temp)
  
  # server code handling logic to save values$df_temp when click "Save to csv"
  observeEvent(input$save_csv, {
    write.csv(values$df_temp, "./words.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Image of sample apps]